# Checkbox not triggering when selected / unselected

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I have a checkbox in my Canvas App that when selected or unselected, does not seem to trigger any behaviour in those properties. I have tried this with both classic and modern controls.

In my Checkbox properties I have:

OnCheck: Collect(SelectedDays, "Wednesday")
OnUncheck: Remove(SelectedDays, ["Wednesday"])

These are adding/removing the selected day to/from a collection. I have managed to get this functionality working via buttons so I know the formulas are correct, but I would prefer to have this happen via Checkbox.

I have tried testing the OnCheck / OnUncheck with a simple UpdateContext({Checked: true}) and UpdateContext({Checked: false}) respectively but it never seems to even reach this behaviour when selecting and unselecting the checkbox.

Are these controls just broken or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Adding context, this is being used within a form in a custom card. The checkboxes seem to work outwith a form but when in a form, they do not seem to perform the same functionality